# Update a Facebook comment using Facebook Graph API with Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am  trying to update a facebook comment by getting it through "comment-id" using facebook-sdk. But I could not find relevant resources. How can I update a specific comment without changing it's comment-id?

I have done something like this

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='XXXXXXX')
comment = graph.get_object(id='ZZZZZ')
```

Now I am trying to update the comment.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/comment#update, hiding/unhiding appears to be the only kind of “update” you can perform on a comment.

Comment: Can't I edit a comment?